# Groovy - merging XML nodes

Tags: xml, parsing, groovy

I'm so close on this but it's just not working for me. I have two XML structures

The structure is Items -> Item (1 to many instances).

I have an existing Item, with Items, and I want to copy all instances from a second copy of Item to the existing one.

```
def newMessage = new XmlParser().parseText(newMsg);
def newItems = newMessage.depthFirst().findAll{it.name() == 'Items'};

def existingMessage = new XmlParser().parse(src); //src is a file location
def existingSettlementItem = existingMessage.depthFirst().findAll{it.name() == 'Items'};
```

This gives me an array list of size 2, which is expected. I can combined the two arrays fine, which will give me a 4 size arrayList of my nodes. How can I get this back to the XML?

Regards,
Chris

Added XML example

```
<Items>
  <SItem>
    <MsgData>
      <BahElements>
        <Fr>
          <Name>
            <Address>
              <Value>123 Fake St</Value>
            </Address>
          </Name>
        </Fr>
        <To>
         <Name>
            <Address>
              <Value>123 Fake St</Value>
            </Address>
          </Name>
        </To>
        <MsgDefIdr>MSG_DEF_IDR_VALUE</MsgDefIdr>
      </BahElements>
    </MsgData>
  </Item>
  <Item>
     <MsgData>
      <BahElements>
        <Fr>
          <Name>
            <Address>
              <Value>123 Fake St</Value>
            </Address>
          </Name>
        </Fr>
        <To>
         <Name>
            <Address>
              <Value>321 Fake St</Value>
            </Address>
          </Name>
        </To>
        <MsgDefIdr>MSG_DEF_IDR_VALUE</MsgDefIdr>
      </BahElements>
    </MsgData>
  </Items>
```

Comment: Do you have a small example xml for `newMsg` and `src`?

Comment: Added there now. The message data would be identical structure wise. Just imagine two of them, and I want to merge all the Item tags from one to within the Items tags of the other.

Comment: @ChrisO'Brien, please the answer to see if that is helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the `groovy script` which does the merging of Item nodes from two xml data into one xml.

All you need to is choose the object where you want merge Item nodes from other xml and append those nodes. 
For instance, Items of xml2 needs to be merged into xml1? Then use:  `xml2Items.collect{ pXml1.Items.appendNode(it)}`

And I believe now you know how to do the merge the otherway i.e., Items of xml1 to merge into xml2.

```
//Create the parsed objects for xml data
def pXml1 = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml1)
def pXml2 = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml2)

//Merge the 2nd xml nodes into 1st xml
pXml2.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'Item'}.collect{ pXml1.Items.appendNode(it)}

//Print the whole merged xml
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(pXml1)
```

You can quickly try this online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5195562143973376)</kbd> with xml sample data provided

Note that the xml sample data is not well-formed, so had changed in the above demo.

Comment: Thanks very much. That did work, but my code was actually fine. Stepping through it with this code sorted it for me. I forgot to set my filewriter append to true. Egg. Face. Thanks though!